# Difference between ActionResult classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, actionresult

What is the difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult and System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ?

When should you use one or the other one?

Comment: You use one with ASP.NET MVC, the other with ASP.NET Core

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) vs [ASP.NET Core ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0): different Frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.Web.Mvc` namespace is used the .NET Framework. If your project is targetting the .NET Framework, use `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult`.

Below list is all return type from [System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) :

- `ViewResult` : Represents HTML and markup.
- ‌`EmptyResult` : Represents no result.
- ‌`RedirectResult` : Represents a redirection to a new URL.
- ‌`JsonResult` : Represents a JavaScript Object Notation result that can
  be used in an AJAX application.
- ‌`JavaScriptResult` : Represents a JavaScript script.
- ‌`ContentResult` : Represents a plain text result.
- ‌`FileContentResult` : Represents a downloadable file (with the binary
  content).
- ‌`FilePathResult` : Represents a downloadable file (with a path).
- ‌`FileStreamResult` : Represents a downloadable file (with a file
  stream).

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace is used in .NET Core. If your project is targetting .NET Core, use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`.

**ASP.NET Core** offers the following options for web API controller action return types:

- `Specific type`
- `IActionResult`
- `ActionResult<T>`

List of common return types in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) :

- `ViewResult` : Represents HTML and markup.
- `ContentResult` : Represents content like plain text, XML, html.
- `JsonResult` : Represents a JavaScript Object Notation result that can be used in an AJAX application.
- `PartialViewResult` : Represents PartialView.
- `RedirectResult` : Represents a redirection to a new URL.
- `RedirectToActionResult` : Represents a redirection to specified action and controller.
- `RedirectToPageResult` : Represents a redirection to a specified pageName (It is mostly used in Razor pages).
- `RedirectToRouteResult` : Represents a route to redirect from one controller to another controller in cases we have more than one route.
- `StatusCodeResult` : Represents an HTTP status code.
- `ViewComponentResult` : Represents a "ViewComponent".
- `ChallengeResult` : on execution invokes `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync`.
- `SignInResult` : on execution invokes `HttpContext.SignInAsync`
- `SignOutResult` : on execution invokes `HttpContext.SignOutAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult**

as it is showing, it is applied in asp.net core. this executes the result operation method asynchronusly. it is the default implementation of IActionResult.

**System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult**
It is applied to ASP.NET MVC. it simply represents the result of an action method. It performs the operation synchronously.

Comment: Synchronous/asynchronous could be in bold to increase readability. Citation needed